# Getting Crash When trying to initiate an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

Almost all of the current navigation in the application is working perfectly fine and when doing the same things for other parts i navigate with.

I am getting this error when trying to navigate from one activity to another:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.package, PID: 15338
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package/ui.activity.AccountActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference
                  at ui.activity.BaseActivity.setInitialFragment(BaseActivity.java:181)
                  at ui.activity.BaseActivity.setInitialFragment(BaseActivity.java:174)
                  at ui.activity.BaseActivity.setInitialFragment(BaseActivity.java:160)
                  at ui.activity.AccountActivity.setInitialFragment(AccountActivity.java:38)
                  at ui.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:56)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I can track where the Null reference is being made and have tried a few things to try and bypass it but they all crash the application.

Here is the block where i initiate the activity:

```
@Override
public void onMyAccountOptionSelected() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccountActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then it gets caught here on `view.getId()`, this one is in baseActivity:

```
private void setInitialFragment(View view, Fragment fragment) {
    if (this.getCurrentFragment() == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(view.getId(), fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

I am initially calling `setInitialFragment()` in AccountActivity which extends my baseActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void setInitialFragment() {

    fragment = (AccountFragment) AccountFragment.newInstance();
    setInitialFragment(fragment);

}
```

As you can see above there is now an AccountFragment, in this class i extend from an abstractFragment and have a method to declare a newInstance:

```
public static Fragment newInstance() {

    AccountFragment fragment = new AccountFragment();
    return fragment;
}
```

I cant find anywhere else where it may be affecting the process used for navigating to this activity. I am hoping to find a method to make a quick fix or to find a more appropriate way to solve this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you calling setInitialFragment?

Comment: @mromer I am updating the above question to be more descriptive. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @mromer i have updated the question to provide a bit more information, i hope that will help you

Comment: don't you get a compile error in this line setInitialFragment(fragment); ? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide us with all the information needed to be really helpfull.

i'm imaging that your setInitialFragment in your AccountActivity would be something like this:

```
public class AccountActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.container);
        AccountFragment fragment = AccountFragment.getInstance(); 
        setInitialFragment(fragment);
    } 

}
```

Based on what you posted, your are calling 2 different methods, this:

```
setInitialFragment(Fragment fragment);
```

is not the same as this

```
setInitialFragment(View view, Fragment fragment)
```

Comment: It does look very similar to that. What do you purpose a solution is for this? I ask because i never wrote this code, I'm coming into a code base i am not 100% familiar with.

Comment: For me, the best place to learn this "pattern" is going through this code [Google IO 2016 Android](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui)
opening the BaseActivity class and is child SearchActivity class to start to learn how this logic should be handled.
It's easy after you start going through the mechanics a little bit

Comment: i have read through the code in those files and i still don't see where it would apply in my position? I have tried many different things and i keep getting the same outcome

Comment: Sorry but there is no way to be more helpfull without knowing the code of BaseActivity and AccountActivity classes

Comment: would there be a time you could maybe do a go to meeting with me where i can share this info more? Im at a spot where i am really pulling out my hair and would really like to understand this pattern a lot better and it would fix almost all the navigation errors i am getting in the application right now

Comment: Sorry but SO it's not intended for this type of help (and honestly i don't have time). I can suggest you to read some tutorials on the net if you can find something usefull, check here : https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20baseactivity%20tutorial

Comment: After further reading and study i removed the old code that was not working and implemented it as instructed by other examples and it is working perfectly fine now without me having to change any of the original views or fragments.